# Start a console application from a WCFService

Tags: c#

I have a solution with a `Console` project and a `WCFService` project.
In the `WCF` I've added a reference to the `Console`.

How do I run the console`from the service?

Do I need to create a new`Process`using`System.Diagnostics;`?

Within the `WCF` I have the following method which is the point where I want to run the console:

```
public String WelComeMessage(String name) {                      
    Process myConsole = new Process(); ///<<<maybe not required?
    //<want run the console here
    return String.Format("{0}, Welcome to http://blah.com", name);
}
```

So in VS it looks like this at the moment:

[image]

Comment: Do I understand you right, do you wanna just start console app or you would like to start console app and read some result from it??

Comment: eventually the console app will be doing various tasks involving a database but for the timebeing it is proof of concept time, and all I want to do is start the console

Comment: Then this two lines of code will be enough: Process p = Process.Start(startInfo); p.WaitForExit(); . If you "own" your console application it would be better to get your business logic inside windows library and then reference it inside wfc service (as Tim S suggested) instead of running as console application. You can still use this library for console application if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you really need to do is make use of the class(es) in the console app, then you can use the class directly instead of running it as a console app, e.g.

```
Program.Main(args);
```

Comment: don't understand if I've added a reference to the namespace of the console app and the class within that class is called Program then why when I try typing in Program does it not recognise it i.e it does not go blue ?

Comment: Most likely, the class `Program` is not `public`.  Mark the class, along with any methods you want to access directly from any external assembly, `public`, and it should appear.

Comment: ok - marked the Class public and we nearly have lift off...but I've marked Main as public and nothing; then realised I don't even have an instance of the object so created a `new` instance and all is now blue!

Answer (score 0):

you can just do `Process.Start("consoleapp.exe")`, but what are you doing?

Comment: WTF? ...is that a type of project I issed? ... I'm feeling around in the dark a bit. Scenario is I have a box (call it X) that I want to run long programs on. I'd like to have a client on my machine that sends short messages to box X and when it receives a valid message the program runs (that's the console)

Comment: did I need the reference to the console?

Comment: not if you know the full path to the .exe.  If you have a reference, you could call the programs Main() directly if you want, but that would be in-process with the wcf call so probably not.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to look into a NServiceBus like solution (i.e. post a message to a queue and have another subscriber process which picks up the message and does work completely.)  http://www.nservicebus.com

Comment: I've been advised that what I'm doing might be a valid path; I'm just new to C# so having to do a lot of exploring (will check out the nservicebus.com)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will be helpfull if you would like to read the result from your console app:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts and returns result from console application. Execution is done without window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exePath">Full path to console exe file</param>
    /// <param name="arguments">console exe parameters</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static string ReadConsoleResult(string exePath, string arguments)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(exePath, arguments);
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        return output;
    }
```